# How to rerun programmatically the program (intellij idea plugin)

Tags: intellij-plugin

I want to programmatically rerun(There is a command for this also you can use ctrl-f5) Below is a picture of rhis button in idea

[image: Rerun button]

So how I can run this action by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the answer on intellij idea development forum

> Hi Evgeniy,
>
> You should use ExecutionManager.restartRunProfile() for that.
>
> Default IJ implementation achieves that via [RestartAction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/execution/runners/RestartAction.java) (the one from your screenshot).
>
> Denis